# Calling spotify API will give me bad request (using Axios) even with AccessToken

Tags: reactjs, api, spotify, axios

```
// If you want your component to get data to render
componentWillMount() {
// Called first time the comp is loaded right before the comp is added to the page
    console.log('Component WILL MOUNT!')

    const BASE_URL = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?';
    const FETCH_URL = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0OdUWJ0sBjDrqHygGUXeCF';
    var accessToken = .......


    axios.get(FETCH_URL, {headers : {'Authorization' : accessToken}})

    .then((response) => {

        console.log(response);


    })

        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
    })
}
```

In my React webapp, I am requesting the api from the URL stated with my accessToken provided. Before I specified my accessToken it gave me a 401 (unauthorized error) but now it gives me 400 (bad request).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this an OAuth2? The header is possible incorrect. It should read `Authorization: Bearer [token string]` or similar.

Comment: You mean something like this? `axios.get(FETCH_URL, {headers : {'Authorization' : Bearer [accessToken]}})`

Comment: Yep, depending on the OAuth2 method, the value (after the colon) should start with the word Bearer followed by a space followed by the token

Answer (score 0):

Use following code, It will help you.

Actually, you need to based on the OAuth2 method, the value (after the colon) should start with the word Bearer followed by a space followed by the token.

If you saw your console then you will get following error response,

```
      {
          "error": {
              "status": 400,
              "message": "Only valid bearer authentication supported"
          }
      }
```

As like @marekful added in comment, for more info please check [spotify](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/) authorization-guide to [here](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/).

```
      accessToken = 'Bearer' + ......;

      axios.get(FETCH_URL, {headers : {'Authorization' : accessToken}})

      .then((response) => {

          console.log(response);


      })

          .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
      })
```

Hopes this will help you!

Comment: I used the exact same code and still getting the 400 Bad Request.

Comment: Can you please call your API in componentDidMount() method?